# How can I change the keyboard shortcuts in Terminal.app for the application commands normally invoked using the unmodified ⇡ and ⇣ keys?

Tags: command-line, shortcut, history

That is, how can I change the keyboard shortcuts for the application commands (I say *application commands* in an attempt to avoid confusion with the use of the term "command" in the *shell command* sense, given that the application under discussion here is Terminal…), that, by default, are accessed using the cursor up and down arrow keys?

I would like to be able to move back and forth through my shell command history using some other pair of keyboard shortcuts than the arrow keys.

I just know somebody will (misguidedly) ask, so I'll state in advance that: the reason is that the unmodified cursor keys have been re-purposed (their new employ is no one's business but mine, and it **certainly** has no bearing on the answer to my question), and the shortcuts I'd like to use instead are <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd>.

Comment: This is something determined by the shell, not by Terminal. Which shell are you using?

Comment: Would `set -o emacs` and using Cmd-P/Cmd-N be an option?

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying: this is for bash.

Comment: Patrix: Excellent! This solved it. Thank you so much!